# Cron job will not run from boot on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, python, boot, cron

I am relatively new to programming and am attempting to run a program from boot using a cron job on a Raspberry pi 2. So I went into the terminal and accessed the cron tab, I then entered `@reboot python /home/pi/Project/Bluetooth.py` (I know that's the right address, I have checked several times). The Python code I am trying to run in the beginning is:

```python
import os
import subprocess

print "Hello World"
os.system('echo "hello world"')

os.system('/usr/bin./galculator')

target = open('test.txt', 'w')
target.write("Why doesn't this work")
target.close()
```

I am simply trying to write some type of code to see if the cron is working and I test the code below in the terminal and everything works (prints hello world twice, opens up calculator, and then creates the text file). But it doesn't do anything on boot.

I tried every thing I could think of by printing to opening up processes. I am running Raspbian that i installed my self and everything else is working ok. I can't really start working on this project until I know it will run at boot. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is that the actual code, or does the real version not have the typos in lines 5, 7 and 9? There's a very good chance that X11 is not up by the time that this script is run, so galculator will have no way to run.

Comment: Sure about that dubious `.` in the ` /usr/bin` path?

Comment: Scruss? What errors? It runs in terminal, am i missing some code in there? I copied it over pretty hastily but I am pretty sure that is it. And Ghanima  the ./ is to run galculator. Is that improper syntax in python?

Comment: /usr/bin./galculator means 'Run galculator in a folder called "/usr/bin." - There is no folder called bin. (with the dot at the end).

Comment: The code above runs in the terminal on PI. It throws some errors but it looks like its for the instance of galculator starting up. Is ./ not run on python? I thought that was a unix thing. It seems like cron isn't running my code right off boot.

Comment: I think your mixing up two things here. `/usr/bin` is a "system" path where many of the binaries/executables reside. `./` on the other hand is refering to the current working directory (cwd). There is normally no such thing as `/usr/bin.` (a folder named "bin."). So where is this `galculator` of yours? Is it in the same folder as this script or is it in `/usr/bin`? Try `which galculator` if in doubt.

Comment: You are using a Raspbian, so you can try to use the /etc/init.d/ for start a program on boot.

more information with the skeleton script : /etc/init.d/skeleton
and here : https://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian but Ghanima is right you have some problem with your script

Comment: Which cron are you trying to start with? Is it the one for user Pi or is it the one for user Root? Are you trying to start this calculator in graphic interface?

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys i figured out what my issue was! Running that code wouldnt work so in the cron tab i had to put the line "@reboot cd /home/pi/Project; sudo python Bluetooth.py &". This worked, I don't know why it wasn't working earlier. But the code would work but i did change the galculator command to what you suggested Gilles. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: As often repeated: there is no need for the "&" in crontab.

Comment: Oh, does it automatically run everything in the back ground on start up?

Comment: Yes, `cron` (+) forks each scheduled job into a separate process so that it will not be attached to cron but runs "in the back ground". (+) Note that this is the common behaviour there might be `cron`-implentations around handling that otherwise (but that seems unlikely).